# unable to install cursor theme

Tags: themes, cursor

I tried to install this cursor theme on the latest version of ubuntu:

http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Microzoa?content=154458

It downloaded as a 7z file, so I extracted it, and copied all the extracted files to usr/share/icons folder. Then I installed  gnome-tweak-tool and I went to advanced settings > theme > icon theme (and selected Microzoa). But then nothing happened. I restarted computer and still the new cursor them doesn't appear at all.

Answer (score 0):

You should select Microzoa as a cursor theme. Make sure you move the microzoa directory to /usr/share/icons and not just its subcontents. I don't think you should have to restart to see the effects.

Comment: I moved all the files and the microzoa directory was one of them and I even moved the contents into that directory as well. And its not one of options under cursor theme

Comment: Are you using Gnome? You can check with `echo $DESKTOP_SESSION` and see that it says gnome and not ubuntu. I don't why it's not appearing under cursor theme -- just make sure you moved everything like `sudo mv ~/Downloads/microzoa /usr/share/icons`